# UISearchBar + didSelectRowAtIndexPath + cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have the following `UITableViewController` + `UISearchBar` setup

```
@interface FeedTableView : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *ArrayDatiOriginali;
    NSMutableArray *searchData;

    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;    
}
```

Below the load method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate=self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;  tableView.
}
```

To select data/rows when the UISeach appear i use

```
if(tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    NSLog(@"Riga corrente: %i",indexPath.row);
    appo=[searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

and it works ok for filtering table view.

But if:

- Search view is active (showing filtered result)
- I click on a row of the filtered result

Then

- `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is fired but
- in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method the expression

  if(tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) return FALSE

also if `UISearchView` is active

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you return `FALSE` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I don't really follow what the problem is - the selection works but after selection the display doesn't?

Comment: I want to update cell image after user select a row in the UISearchResultController. For this the didSelectRowAtIndexPath works ok, but I need to reload the UISearch cell/table to update the image

Comment: Fine. You should be updating your data model as a result of the selection and then reloading the table. This reloads the cell which takes the new information from the data model.

Comment: @user3197643 Did you find the answer? I have same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Make Two Arrays.

`dataArray` & `filteredDataArray`
& Make a BOOL isFiltered.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
if(text.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = true;
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
{
isFiltered = FALSE;
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(isFiltered)
{
    <#YOUR_MODEL#>= [filteredDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    <#YOUR_MODEL#>= [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
int rowCount;
if(isFiltered)
    rowCount = [filteredDataArray count];
else
    rowCount = [dataArray count];
return rowCount;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
if(isFiltered)
{
    <#YOUR_MODEL#>= [filteredDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    <#YOUR_MODEL#>= [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
//Pass it to any class or do what ever.
}
```

Comment: I added -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text but the method is not being called...how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, you also need to add:

```
searchBar.delegate = self;
```

The searchBar will then be able to call

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
```